# Asp-net 3.1 how to edit fields using summernote (Or any other rich text editor)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some fields in my database that contain strings that produce html i.e. "<p'>Hello world</p'>".
I'm trying to bring these through to a summernote rich text editor so they can be edited from there.
I've tried

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="MainText" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div asp-for="MainText" id="summernote"></div>
                <span asp-validation-for="MainText" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#summernote').summernote();
           });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and that isn't working. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can approach this?

Comment: Try using an input or textarea instead of div. That should allow it without any other changes. In old aspnet forms, I used @Html.EditorFor to create the area with success.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was the solution I eventually came to.

Comment: Happy days. Is nice to play around with all the extras you can do on the initialize of summer note. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Update because I'm a dumbass.
The documentation I read said that I needed to use a div to put the summernote id attribute in, however it turns out you can also use a text area, as displayed below. This is working fine now.

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="MainText" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea asp-for="MainText" id="summernote"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="MainText" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#summernote').summernote();
           });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```